# Scan for barcodes only when button held

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` to read bar codes. It calls the delegate method..

`captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`

...when it matches something.

How can I make it ignore matches unless a user is holding their finger on a button?

Comment: Call `func setMetadataObjectsDelegate(_ objectsDelegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate!, queue objectsCallbackQueue: DispatchQueue!)` only when you start to hold the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add multiple actions to your button. Catch when the user presses down, set a read bar codes state. Catch when the user lets go, clear the read bar code state.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonDown), for:.touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonUp), for:.touchUpInside)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonUp), for:.touchUpOutside)
    ...
}

func buttonDown() {
    startReadBarcode() 
}

func buttonUp() {
    stopReadBarcode()
}
```

Comment: I think I will set a flag on button down and unset it on button up. That will have minimal effect on the delegate method.

Comment: Why would I use gesture recognisers when this so much simpler.

Comment: I dont' know. It's all new to me.

Comment: I don't think it works though. It's too difficult to keep track of the button state. For example, if you hold the button and click home screen, the button gets stuck in the on state.

Comment: You can check for .touchCancel as well

Comment: Nice. Although I realised my scheme doesn't make sense anyway. My code is always scanning for a code - unlike a bonafide hand held reader. So my button really only needs to trigger a process of a bar code if there's currently a match. I can disable the button if there's no existing match.

Comment: I think that will use the battery up, though. So, I'm using .touchCancel and starting and stopping the session when the button is pressed and released.